# Detect click when the allow Button in the notification alert permission is tapped

Tags: swift, push-notification, notifications, popup, alert

[image: Alert Image]

I'm developing this iOS app with SwiftUI.

How I can detect when the user clicks the allow button of the Notification permission alert? It should happen only one time and I need to take the user to a specific tab the first time he tapped the button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the attribute `onclick="location.href='https://google.com';"`.

but could you post codesnippets? and do you use javascript and php?

Comment: I'm using Swift

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. To create this behaviour, I simply saved in a UserDefault a Bool value.

```
 func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { [weak self] granted, _ in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            
            self?.userDefault.set(granted, forKey: "notificationGranted")

            guard granted else {
                return
            }

            self?.getNotificationSettings()
        }
}

      func getNotificationSettings() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else {
            return
        }
        // Saving the value to permit to take the user to the Notification screen only the first time
        if (self.userDefault.value(forKey: "permissionPopUpIsShowed") == nil) {
            self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: "permissionPopUpIsShowed")
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}
```

In the Content View inside the onAppear method you can do this:

```
                        if appDelegate.userDefault.bool(forKey: "permissionPopUpIsShowed") == true && appDelegate.userDefault.bool(forKey: "notificationGranted") == true {
                        tabSelection = .notifications
                        appDelegate.userDefault.set(false, forKey: "permissionPopUpIsShowed")
                    }
```

In this way you will be able to select a new view (through the tabSelection) and obtain this behaviour only once (when the notification permission popUp is showed).